# Get particular columns with SPFx?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, typescript

Im developing some web parts with SPFx and one of the things I'm trying to do is get certain coluumns from a list to display them.

I use the guide https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/connect-to-sharepoint but the problem I'm having lies here ...

Under "Define List Model" it is hardcoding the columns that are returned...

```
export interface ISPLists {
  value: ISPList[];
}

export interface ISPList {
  Title: string;
  Id: string;
}
```

Would it be possible to say define a property (lets call it columnsToShow) and if that contains a comma delimited list then it would show those values?
For example if columnsToShow = "Title,CustomerID,CustomerContactNo"
that I would be able to see those values in ISPList?

Thanks
P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, In the sample it [queries list collection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/connect-to-sharepoint#retrieve-lists-from-sharepoint-site) from SPO, and the properties 'title'/'id' belongs to the list.

> private _getListData(): Promise {   return
> this.context.spHttpClient.get(this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl
>
> - '/_api/web/**lists**?$filter=Hidden eq false', SPHttpClient.configurations.v1)
>   .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {
>   return response.json();
>   }); }

They're not fields(columns). If you want to query items and specify the expected columns, you may take a reference of the below tutorial:

- https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/retrieve-sharepoint-list-items-using-sharepoint-framework-development-model/

And I suggest you use pnpjs in your web part:

- https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/items/#basic-get

BR